# Mercurial get project repository

Tags: mercurial

How can I get mercurial to print out the full path of the repository I am working in? I'm looking for something similar, that `svn info` provides with the `URL` property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
hg paths
```

would output all the configured remote repositories for the current working copy.

Answer (score 0):

Fundamental difference between DVCS (Mercurial) and CVCS (Subversion) is, well... first letter - in case of distributed system you have not single authoritative source.

I.e nothing **directly correlated** with SVN-URL can not exist in Mercurial

> full path of the repository I am working in?

Because you working in *local repository*, dumb answer is `hg root`

> hg root
>
> print the root (top) of the current working directory

but `hg paths default` can be *somehow* considered as poor-man iteration to URL in Subversion world